# response redirect sending source page when not needed

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, web

I am trying to find a resolution to a Response.Redirect issue. The simple code to redirect is as follows.

Response.Redirect(Uri, true);

or

Response.Redirect(Uri, false);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

When I use the first method, the 302 message is something less than 200 bytes in size. When I use the second method the 302 message also adds the full source page for no benefit and can bloat the message to over 200,000 bytes when there is a lot of view state. I am aware that the first method will cause a ThreadAbortException which I would like to avoid if possible. I would like to use the second method and have the 302 be back to the less than 200 bytes. The performance of my site is taking a hit with all this extra data being sent on the 302’s when it is not needed. I am looking for a way to avoid having the source page added to the 302 in the “right” way without the exceptions.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Confused... You want to prevent the response from ending early, though don't want to send any response back with the redirect? What is the issue with using the first method?

Comment: If this is all just to avoid the `ThreadAbortException` being thrown based on aesthetic reasons, I'd strongly suggest learning to live with it. You already know the *fast* way to achieve the *small* 302 - it's option 1.